# Column delimiters in responsive design

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

Let's say I have 4 icons that I want to lay out responsively so that they are horizontal if there is space and vertical otherwise:

```
Desktop:
□ | □ | □ | □

Tablet:
□ | □
□ | □

Mobile:
□
□
□
□
```

In Bootstrap this can be done rather easily with the grid system where each icon will be placed inside a column:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 icon">
```

But my questions is about those delimiters you see in the diagram. I want to use simple border property to draw vertical line between the icons, something like this:

```
.icon {
    border-left: 1px solid #333;
}
.icons:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}
```

This will remove the left border on the first icon and everything looks great on desktop but I need to do something similar for other layouts too, that is remove the border from third icon in tablet layout and remove all the borders in mobile layout. The one off solution would be to use media query but **is there a way how to do this intelligently for any number of elements in a row and various layouts?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@media` queries :

```
/* Default all border except first one (left). */
.icon {
    border-left: 1px solid #333;
}
.icon:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

/* Tablet (check the value with bootstrap), only even child have left border. */
@media (max-width: 992px) {

    .icon:nth-child(odd) {
        border-left: none ;
    }

}

/* On mobile, no border. */
@media (max-width: 768px) {

    .icon {
        border-left: none ;
    }

}
```

The value I chose (768 and 992) are the values used by bootstrap to set the width on `col-xx-x`. This will unfortunately not work on old browser (need `first-child` and `nth-child`).

Comment: I was looking for general/automated solution but now I have realised that the division into bootstrap grid is no general/automated and has to be done manually for give number of icons and layouts. Can you please update your answer to mention the nth-child((an + b) instead of just nth-child(odd)? Thanks